# `this[object Key]` unlimited number of arguments

Tags: c#, this

I want to make `this[object key]` take an unlimited number of arguments, how can I do this?

For example, I have a code -

```
public class Response
{
    public object this[object Key]
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Response response = new Response();

        var test = response["fds"]; //I can do this
        var test2 = response["fds"]["dsa"]; //But this is how I cannot do
    }
}
```

How can I do as shown in `test2` so that I can take an unlimited number of arguments?

Comment: That would require that whatever `this` is returning have it's own indexer, not that the indexer supports multiple arguments, by the syntax you've shown. Do you want a single indexer (`response["fds","dsa"];`) or for the returned object to have it's own indexer?

Comment: `var test3 = JObject.Parse(Response.ToString())["fd"]["fdhgfd"];`

For example, this is done by Json.NET.
I have to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your syntax, you probably want to return `dynamic` rather than `object` (so you can write the second index invocation without ceremony). When you're returning something that is meant to allow deeper access, you'd return something `Response`-like:

```
public class Response
{
    public dynamic this[object Key]
    {
        get
        {
            if(Key is int)
            {
               return "Hello";
            }
            else
            {
                return new Response();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll hopefully have a clearer idea of how these nested objects will relate together and so may not need to `new` up one, or it may be some other class that exposes a similar indexer as `Response`.

This line, using the above definition:

```
var test3 = response["fds"]["dsa"]["jkl"][5];
```

Should produce "Hello".

Since you mentioned JSON.Net, it's approach doesn't use `dynamic` - but it's [`JToken.Item`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) indexer always returns an object of the same type - another `JToken`. That's how you might choose to solve it but you wouldn't be returning a plain `"Hello"` as an alternative any longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you return object than it has no such property. You have to cast it to some kind of object

```
public class Response : IResponse
{
    public object this[object Key]
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
public interface IResponse
{
    object this[object Key] { get; }
}
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Response response = new Response();

        var test = response["fds"]; //I can do this
        var test2 = (response["fds"] as IResponse)?["dsa"]; //But response["fds"] have to be IResponse if it's not you will get null
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this, but Json.Net did it like this - `var test3 = JObject.Parse (Response.ToString ())[" fd "][" fdhgfd "];`, but I never found the answer and now in a small stupor

Comment: JObject.Parse returns `JObject` (`JToken`) where you can get properties by index `Item[Object]`, see [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)